# Troubleshooting AJAX behavior in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm building a simple Rails [application](https://github.com/O-I/pluck) to manage my favorites list on Twitter. I built a few simple rake tasks to pull all the tweets I have favorited and any new ones I favorite in the future into a database.

I've managed to implement infinite scroll on my index view by following the RailsCast on [Endless Page](http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page-revised). I also followed [RailsCast #228](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns) to create several sortable navigation links that display the index view by newest (freshest), oldest (ripest), most favorited (sweetest), most retweeted (juiciest), and randomly (unpickiest).

Now I'm trying to get those navigation links to work using AJAX, but I'm having trouble making it behave correctly with the infinite scroll. The links work as you would expect if you click on them without scrolling. But if you scroll even just a little, clicking on another navigation link will hit the database twice, loading the first 25 favorites sorted as you would expect and an additional 25 that correspond to the next page of the previous sorted view.

For example, this is what my Rails server shows locally when I navigate to freshest, to ripest, scroll a wee bit, go to sweetest, and finally to juiciest. Notice that when I load by sweetest its also loading page 2 of ripest:

```
Started GET "/?col=date_tweeted&dir=DESC&_=1397073954001" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-09 16:06:01 -0400
Processing by FavoritesController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"col"=>"date_tweeted", "dir"=>"DESC", "_"=>"1397073954001"}
  Favorite Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "favorites".* FROM "favorites" ORDER BY date_tweeted DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
   (1.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "favorites"
  Rendered favorites/_favorite.html.erb (23.3ms)
  Rendered favorites/index.js.erb (40.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 45ms (Views: 41.6ms | ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)


Started GET "/?col=date_tweeted&dir=ASC&_=1397073954002" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-09 16:06:08 -0400
Processing by FavoritesController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"col"=>"date_tweeted", "dir"=>"ASC", "_"=>"1397073954002"}
  Favorite Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "favorites".* FROM "favorites" ORDER BY date_tweeted ASC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
   (1.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "favorites"
  Rendered favorites/_favorite.html.erb (71.4ms)
  Rendered favorites/index.js.erb (92.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 97ms (Views: 93.2ms | ActiveRecord: 3.1ms)


Started GET "/?col=favorite_count&dir=DESC&_=1397073954003" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-09 16:06:14 -0400
Processing by FavoritesController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"col"=>"favorite_count", "dir"=>"DESC", "_"=>"1397073954003"}
  Favorite Load (5.5ms)  SELECT "favorites".* FROM "favorites" ORDER BY favorite_count DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
   (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "favorites"
  Rendered favorites/_favorite.html.erb (72.2ms)
  Rendered favorites/index.js.erb (90.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 97ms (Views: 89.9ms | ActiveRecord: 6.3ms)


Started GET "/?_=1397073954004&col=date_tweeted&dir=ASC&page=2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-09 16:06:14 -0400
Processing by FavoritesController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"_"=>"1397073954004", "col"=>"date_tweeted", "dir"=>"ASC", "page"=>"2"}
  Favorite Load (5.0ms)  SELECT "favorites".* FROM "favorites" ORDER BY date_tweeted ASC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 25
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "favorites"
  Rendered favorites/_favorite.html.erb (28.1ms)
  Rendered favorites/index.js.erb (44.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 50ms (Views: 43.3ms | ActiveRecord: 5.6ms)


Started GET "/?col=retweet_count&dir=DESC&_=1397073954005" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-09 16:06:19 -0400
Processing by FavoritesController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"col"=>"retweet_count", "dir"=>"DESC", "_"=>"1397073954005"}
  Favorite Load (3.0ms)  SELECT "favorites".* FROM "favorites" ORDER BY retweet_count DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
   (1.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "favorites"
  Rendered favorites/_favorite.html.erb (73.7ms)
  Rendered favorites/index.js.erb (91.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 96ms (Views: 91.4ms | ActiveRecord: 4.1ms)
```

I'm having trouble understanding how to eliminate the page parameter when switching between the different ways to sort the index view (do I set it to `nil`? when? where?). The code is [here](https://github.com/O-I/pluck), and a demo of the application without AJAX sorting is [here](http://kerpluck.herokuapp.com/). For convenience, below is a copy of the most relevant code. Thanks for your help.

```
//favorites.js.coffee
endlessScroll = ->
  if ('.pagination').length
    $(window).scroll ->
      url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
      if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
        $('.pagination').text('Plucking more favorites...')
        $.getScript(url)
    $(window).scroll()

jQuery ->
  endlessScroll()

//application.js
$(function() {
  var sortOptions = 'ul.left > li > a';
  $(sortOptions).on('click', function() {
    $(sortOptions).css({ background: '#333333' });
    $(this).css({ background: '#f04124' });
    $('#all-favorites').empty();
    // remove page params ???
    // or remove .pagination for now ???
    $.getScript(this.href);
    return false;
  });
});

//index.html.erb
<div class='row' id='all-favorites'>
  <%= render @favorites %>
</div>

<%= will_paginate @favorites %>

//index.js.erb
$('#all-favorites').append('<%= j render(@favorites) %>');
<% if @favorites.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@favorites) %>');
<% else %>
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>

//_topbar.html.erb snippet
 <ul class='left'>
    <li><%= sortable 'freshest', 'date_tweeted' %></li>
    <li><%= sortable 'ripest', 'date_tweeted', 'ASC' %></li>
    <li><%= sortable 'sweetest', 'favorite_count' %></li>
    <li><%= sortable 'juiciest', 'retweet_count' %></li>
    <li><%= shufflable 'unpickiest'%></li>
  </ul>

//application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def sortable(link_name, column, direction = 'DESC')
    link_to link_name, col: column, dir: direction
  end

  def shufflable(link_name)
    link_to link_name, mix: true
  end
end

//favorites_controller.rb
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @favorites = Favorite.order(sort).page(params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @favorite = Favorite.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def sort
    shuffle? ? 'RANDOM()' : "#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}"
  end

  def sort_column
    sortable_columns = %w(date_tweeted favorite_count retweet_count)
    sortable_columns.include?(params[:col]) ? params[:col] : 'date_tweeted'
  end

  def sort_direction
    %w(ASC DESC).include?(params[:dir]) ? params[:dir] : 'DESC'
  end

  def shuffle?
    params[:mix] == 'true'
  end
end
```

Comment: Why are calling `$(window).scroll()` at the end of your endlessScroll function?

Comment: @TimeEmit According to the RailsCast: "If the user’s browser window is tall enough to display all of the first page the second page of products will then automatically be loaded." I tried removing it (and can likely do without it as I load 25 records at a time), but no luck. I think you are really close, though. What seems to be happening is that when I empty the all-favorites div in application.js, the pagination still exists (I can see it flash). Doing something like $('.pagination').text('Resorting...') after the empty() call seems to fix it. Does that make sense? Thanks for your help!